# Create a single VCard file with multiple entries using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, vcf-vcard

I used the code from this [**github gist**](https://gist.github.com/dun4n/9353031) that allows you to save a single content into a VCF file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="vcard2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // From JSON
        var johnSmith = {
            "version": "4.0",
            "n": "SMITH;John;;",
            "fn": "John Smith",
            "nickname":"js",
            "title": "Missing man too",
            "tel": [
                {"value": "555-555-555", "type": "cell"}
            ],
            "email": [
                { "value": "john.smith@work.com", "type": "work" },
                { "value": "john.smith@home.com", "type": "home" }
            ]
        }
        var link = vCard.export(johnSmith, "John Smith", false) // use parameter true to force download
        document.body.appendChild(link)
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This worked for single content as file see [**JSfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6kvyjo5a/1/).
My question is how to add multiple contents into same VCF file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the fiddle you provided just edit the `dump()` function to accept array. Then iterate the array and perform the exact same operations, combining the output (split with `\n`) into one variable.

```
    dump: function(cards) {
        var cardsLength = cards.length;
        var cardsStr = "";

        for (var cardsIndex = 0; cardsIndex < cardsLength; cardsIndex++) {

            var card = cards[cardsIndex];
            //...existing code... just remove the return
             cardsStr+=str+"\n";
        }
        return cardsStr;
    }
```

Now call `vCard.export()` and pass an array of objects instead of object.

Try it here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rjva4e0t/)